# Android Phonegap plugin and google analytics

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, google-analytics

I am using phonegap plugin and I could not get it to work.  In the plugin, there is a plugin.xml and may I know how this file should be set up.

I have mine configured as below and it does not work.

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="plugins">
        <feature name="GAPlugin" >
            <param name="android-package"                     value="com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/com/learnchn/pinyin/GAPlugin.java"
            target-dir="src/com/learnchn/pinyin" />
    <source-file src="libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar"
            target-dir="libs" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Have you used the Command line tools to generate the android project?

Comment: You mean plugman?  I have used Eclipse to generate the apk.

Comment: I have never tried plugman, it seems it is very different from using Eclipse.  For example, will the plugman generate an android manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

`plugin.xml` is a file that is meant to be read and executed by tools such as the plugman to install a plugin to a platform. If you are not using such a tool then you may try to do the steps manually. Basically insert `<feature>` to `res/xml/config.xml` and copy *src* files on `<source-file>` to *target-dir*.

However I doubt that the plugin.xml you have posted is valid. The value for `"android-package"` parameter should point to the plugin implementation.  The value "`com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin"` would suggest that there would be a corresponding source file or a library with that class name added as part of the installation. However the only file that is added with a close name is "`com/learnchn/pinyin/GAPlugin.java`" which has a different package name.

Comment: I have misunderstood the plugman thing and the plugin.xml file and so the plugin.xml is definitely not valid.

Comment: Yes, got it to work.  I create the relevant folders for com/adobe/plugin and put the java file there.  In config.xml, I have these lines: <feature name="GAPlugin" >
    <param name="android-package" value="com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin"/>
 </feature>

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to build your project with phonegap. Navigate to the location where you want to create your project and do the following:

```
phonegap create test com.example.test Test
cd test
phonegap local build android
```

Now you have a working android project in your "platforms/android/" directory which you can import in eclipse. Download the [GAPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin) and unzip it. Then just use plugman to install the Google Analytics Plugin.

```
plugman install --platform android --project (Path to your phonegap android project) --plugin (path to the GAPlugin)
```

Now everything should be set and the plugin is installed. The next step would be initializing the plugin in your index.html to track every page visit. Add the GAPlugin.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="GAPlugin.js"></script>
```

You should add the following code after you received the "deviceready" event.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var gaPlugin;
function onDeviceReady() {
  gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
  gaPlugin.init(successHandler, errorHandler, "UA-********-*", 10);
  // Put this function everywhere you want to track something
  gaPlugin.trackPage( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "index.html");

  function successHandler() {}

  function errorHandler() {} 

  function nativePluginResultHandler() {}

  function nativePluginErrorHandler() {}
}
```

This approach worked for me. I'm using Phonegap 3.0 with the CLI.
Hope this fixes your problems ;)

Comment: Thanks, will try this if I could not get the Eclipse method to work.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to add simple google Analytics setup then its quite easy just follow the below steps

1:- Add libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar in libs folder 2:- Add analytics.xml file inside res->values, it binds the trackingid with the app,u can google for this file 3:-Add import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.easyTracker; in the activity file and use EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); in onCreate function.

Thats it, you are done with Google Analytics basic setup